# On the series of the product of the terms of two sequences whose respective series are one convergent and the other not

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let us consider two sequences of real numbers $a_n$ and $b_n$, about which we only know that: 
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n = 0$$ 
and that all $b_n > 0$, with  $b_{n+1} > b_n$. Can it be proved that there cannot exist a $b_n$ sequence with said features, such that also
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n b_n = 0  \;\;?$$
or is such hypothesis unjustified, and there instead exist counterexamples ?

Thanks

Following Mark's reply, I am reformulating into a somewhat different question, which is also of interest to me.

Given the above conditions for $a_n$ and $b_n$, would it be possible to find  additional general conditions for the $a_n$'s which will then be sufficient to ensure that
$$\sum_{1}^{\infty}a_n b_n \neq 0  \;\;?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the series $a=1-1+1/4-1/4+1/9-1/9...+1/n^2-1/n^2...$ and $b=1+1+2+2+3+3+4+4...+n+n...$ . Their "product" is $1-1+1/2-1/2....1/n-1/n...$ converges to 0.If you really want $b_{n+1}\gt b_n$, then instead $...n+n...$ consider the series $...n+(n+1/n^2)...$.

Comment: but doesn't your $a_n$ in fact resemble a bit too closely 0+0+0+0+.... ?  thanks anyway, as you made me realize that  I shall perhaps better reformulate my question with more constraints on ${a_n}$

Comment: No it does not.  If you want all $a_n$ to be dfferent in absolute value, add any other series where the sum is 0 and the terms converge to 0 faster than $1/n^4$.